# Dynamically change JTable cell value at focus lost

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield, tablecelleditor

I have a JTable whose cell editor is a JTextField, I am invoking focuslost on the celleditor
whose code is

```
public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)
{
 JTextField textField = new JTextField();
 textField = (JTextField) e.getSource();
 textField.setText(getCurrencyEquivalent(textField.getText()));//read P.S
 table.setValueAt(textField.getText(), table.getEditingRow(), 0);
}
```

I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

When I debugged, it was clear that the focuslost is triggered on the cellEditor after the the focus is actually Lost from the JTable's cell. Which makes table.getEditingRow() always return -1, hence it is highly impossible to dynamically set the values at focuslost. Help me solve this by any other technique, if available.

P.S: getCurrencyEquivalent() is a method that returns a formatted version of a given String in a different String format.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  The `JTable` API/`CellEditor` should be taking care of this for you, you should either be calling `stopCellEditing` or `cancelCellEditing`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> getCurrencyEquivalent() is a method that returns a formatted version of a given String in a different String format.

Don't use a FocusListener to try to change the format of the data when it is edited.

Instead, you should be using a custom renderer to format the data. Check out [Table Format Renderers](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/table-format-renderers/) for an easy example of how you can do this.

Comment: Thank you, creating a custom cell renderer solved it